# Order of Symmetric groups

Tags: group-theory

If G=Sym(8) is the symmetric group on 8 letters, how do I find the number of elements in G that have order 7?

Answer (score 1):

Permutations of order $7$ must be products of disjoint cycles of length $7$. Since you only have $8$ elements altogether, everything boils down to cycles of length $7$ of which there are $\frac17\cdot8!$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you give an example of a cycle with order 7?

Comment: sorry I mean element with order 7

Comment: E.g. $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7)$

Comment: Thank you. I am self teaching myself this topic so am struggling a bit. How have you arrived at 1/7 * 8!?

Comment: This is very standard: suppose more generally that you want to count cycles of length $k$ out of $n$ elements ($k\leq n$). You have to pick a first element ($n$ possibilities), a second element ($n-1$ possibilities), and so fort till you choose the $k$-th element ($n-k+1$ possibilities) for a grand total of $n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ different possibilities. But then you need to remember that there are $k$-different ways to write the same cycle, depending on which one you start with. Thus you have to divide the previous total by $k$. In your example $n=8$, $k=7$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. thank you very much.